# in C# .net check exists or not entered string

Tags: c#

```
 protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Console where Text = @TextTmp" );
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@TextTmp";
            param.Value = txtString.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = txtString.Text + "User Id already exists";
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = txtString.Text + "No data";
            }
```

i am writing code for from database i need to check String exists or no if not there update and it has to all the information in the web page how can do that please
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); here is coming error

i am using only single field in c# i took masterpage and adding content page to that and i did but not getting

Comment: What string do you need to check?

Comment: the question isnt clear? what is the error you get?

Comment: @mohannaidu - What error?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what you're trying to do, but try [String.IsNullOrEmpty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're wanted to check the text coming out of here: txtString.Text

You can check via

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtString.Text))
{
     // Handle this scenario
}
```

or via

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtString.Text))
{
     // Handle this scenario
}
```

Comment: i am running with stored procedure

Comment: But you can check the value of txtString.Text before you make any sort of database call to validate your data, regardless of it being a stored procedure or not.